# Computing grid computations using numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, simulation

I have used numpy meshgrids for a long time, and typically find no issues when trying to pass that meshgrid through a function. In my experience it has always been the case that I can define my coordinate space as

```
x,y,z = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.linspace(-10,10,10),
                       numpy.linspace(-10,10,10),
                       numpy.linspace(-10,10,10))
```

and then can easily compute something like
`u,v,w = numpy.sin(x*y)+numpy.cos(z)`.

My issue has arisen from the need to do a cross product in that calculation. I am defining a field using the meshgrid, and trying to pass the entire meshgrid through the function:

```
field_equation = lambda x,y,z: sum([parameter*np.cross([wire_x[i],wire_y[i],wire_z[i]],[x,y,z]) for i in range(len(wire))])
```

Depending on how I try to solve the problem, I get a whole host of problems. The code works fine when passing individual points (x,y,z) through one at a time, but cannot calculate for the entire field. How do I get around this?

Comment: what is `wire`? (if array what is its dimension?) Same for `parameter`?

Comment: @9mat: wire is a class which is essentially composed of 3 lists of points (x,y,z). As such, wire_x[i] is an individual number. The parameter is a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.cross` only accept a vector of size 3, or nd-array with the last dimension of size 3, so we need to stack `np.stack([x,y,z])` to create a `10*10*10*3` nd-array first.

The results will be a `10*10*10*3` array, and to be able to unpack this array later, we need to transpose it to size `3*10*10*10`, so I swap axes of resulting array at the end.

In the code below, I also take the liberty to shorten the code wrt `wire` a little, assuming `wire_x, wire_y, wire_z` are just 3 components of `wire`.

```
import numpy as np

# test data
x,y,z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10,10,10),
                    np.linspace(-10,10,10),
                    np.linspace(-10,10,10))

wire = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [3,4,5,6]]
parameter = 1

field_equation = lambda x,y,z: sum([parameter*np.cross(w, np.stack([x,y,z], axis=-1)) for w in zip(*wire)]).swapaxes(0,-1)

a,b,c = field_equation(x,y,z)
print(a.shape, b.shape, c.shape)

#(10, 10, 10) (10, 10, 10) (10, 10, 10)
```

Comment: This worked great, except that when passing through individual values, the code is correct, but doing so with a mesh grid creates incorrect results. I completely unsure as to why...